# ansible template append to file

Tags: templates, ansible

The below code is being used to append to a config file. What I want to do is introduce a loop `loop: "{{ INTERFACE }}"`, but this does not work (as the temp file will be overwritten), `template` doesn't have an append option.

Any suggestions on how to fix?

```yaml
- name: Build CE config Cisco
  template:
    src=/opt/netsec/ansible/orchestration/cisco_templates/NOKIA_T1_PORT.js
    dest=/opt/netsec/ansible/orchestration/config_outputs/tmp/{{CE_HOSTNAME}}
   loop: "{{ INTERFACE }}"

- name: Build PE config Cisco output
  shell: cat /opt/netsec/ansible/orchestration/config_outputs/tmp/{{CE_HOSTNAME}} >> /opt/netsec/ansible/orchestration/config_outputs/new/{{CE_HOSTNAME}}.conf
```

`INTERFACES` looks like this:

```yaml
INTERFACES:
  - INTERFACE: Gi0/3/0
    EQUIPMENT_DESCRIPTION: ETHXXXXSR01
  - INTERFACE: Gi0/3/1
    EQUIPMENT_DESCRIPTION: ETHXXXXSR01_STANDBY
```

Comment: What you have in `{{ INTERFACE }}` is not clear. However you should probably loop on `INTERFACE` inside the template file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to iterate over a list of list in jinja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056622/how-to-iterate-over-a-list-of-list-in-jinja)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't think I can do this because the file already exists with content that is not being added in by this section.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending files with Template Module in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46366526/appending-files-with-template-module-in-ansible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the template is multi-line

```yaml
shell> cat nokia_t1_port.j2
Equipment {{ item.EQUIPMENT_DESCRIPTION }}
  interface {{ item.INTERFACE }}
```

use [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html). For example

```yaml
    - blockinfile:
        insertafter: EOF
        path: ce_hostname.conf
        block: "{{ lookup('template', 'nokia_t1_port.j2') }}"
        marker: ""
      loop: "{{ INTERFACES }}"
```

gives

```sh
shell> cat ce_hostname.conf

Equipment ETHXXXXSR01_STANDBY
  interface Gi0/3/1

Equipment ETHXXXXSR01
  interface Gi0/3/0
```

Because of the "marker", there will an empty line among the appended blocks.

---

If the template is single-line

```yaml
shell> cat nokia_t1_port.j2
{{ item.EQUIPMENT_DESCRIPTION }} interface {{ item.INTERFACE }}
```

use [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html). For example

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        insertafter: EOF
        path: ce_hostname.conf
        line: "{{ lookup('template', 'nokia_t1_port.j2') }}"
      loop: "{{ INTERFACES }}"
```

gives

```sh
shell> cat ce_hostname.conf
ETHXXXXSR01 interface Gi0/3/0
ETHXXXXSR01_STANDBY interface Gi0/3/1
```

Answer (score 1):

From the description, it sounds like you would like to use the existing contents of `NOKIA_T1_PORT.js` file, but add some content using `INTERFACES` at the destination.

However you can not do this with one `template` task. You could do something like this:

```yaml
- name: Build CE config Cisco
  copy:
    src: /opt/netsec/ansible/orchestration/cisco_templates/NOKIA_T1_PORT.js
    dest: "/opt/netsec/ansible/orchestration/config_outputs/tmp/{{ CE_HOSTNAME }}"

- name: Update interface info
  blockinfile:
    path: "/opt/netsec/ansible/orchestration/config_outputs/tmp/{{ CE_HOSTNAME }}"
    block: |
      {% for item in INTERFACES %}
      INTERFACE: {{ item.INTERFACE }}
      EQUIPMENT_DESCRIPTION: {{ item.EQUIPMENT_DESCRIPTION }}
      {% endfor %}
```